# Long time taking to load the oracle apex form page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

There are 60 Items in a region showing as a group of 10 rows, 6 Items each.
Initially Items are hidden and each group is getting shown based on a button click.

But the page is taking too long time (10 sec apx) to load the page, same goes for validation also.
Any help here...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uncheck the True or False Actions of DA which Fire on Page load as much as you can.

Page will load fast or we can move few conditions to validation with a generic condition can be another approach of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the debug data ? It shows very clearly what specific section is consuming a lot of time. Once you know what is causing the page to be slow you can start working on a solution.
You can read about debug here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/utilizing-debug-mode.htm#HTMDB10003

--Koen